# Issues with gpu::resize

Tags: c++, opencv, pattern-recognition

I am trying to calculate HOG features on GPU for different levels and then I am saving features of each level to a yml file. Below is the function that I am using.

```
void App::run()
{
    unsigned int count = 0;
    FileStorage fs;
    running = true;

    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;

    Size win_size(args.win_width, args.win_width * 2); 
    Size win_stride(args.win_stride_width, args.win_stride_height);

    cv::gpu::HOGDescriptor gpu_hog(win_size, Size(16, 16), Size(8, 8), Size(8, 8), 9,
                                   cv::gpu::HOGDescriptor::DEFAULT_WIN_SIGMA, 0.2, gamma_corr,
                                   cv::gpu::HOGDescriptor::DEFAULT_NLEVELS);

    VideoCapture vc("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/getdescriptor/images/image%d.jpg");
    Mat frame;
    Mat Left;
    Mat img_aux, img, img_to_show, img_new;
    cv::Mat temp;
    gpu::GpuMat gpu_img, descriptors, new_img;

    char cbuff[20];


    while (running)
    {

        vc.read(frame);

        if (!frame.empty())
        {
            workBegin();

            sprintf (cbuff, "%04d", count);

            // Change format of the image
            if (make_gray) cvtColor(frame, img_aux, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            else if (use_gpu) cvtColor(frame, img_aux, CV_BGR2BGRA);
            else Left.copyTo(img_aux);

            // Resize image
            if (args.resize_src) resize(img_aux, img, Size(args.width, args.height));
            else img = img_aux;
            img_to_show = img;

            gpu_hog.nlevels = nlevels;

            hogWorkBegin();
            if (use_gpu)
            {
                gpu_img.upload(img);
                new_img.upload(img_new);
                fs.open(cbuff, FileStorage::WRITE);

                //double scale = 1.05;
                for(int levels = 0; levels < nlevels; levels++)
                {
                gpu_hog.getDescriptors(gpu_img, win_stride, descriptors, cv::gpu::HOGDescriptor::DESCR_FORMAT_ROW_BY_ROW);
                descriptors.download(temp);

                printf("size %d %d\n", temp.rows, temp.cols);

                fs <<"level" << levels;                
                fs << "features" << temp;

                cout<<"("<<width<<","<<height<<")"<<endl;

                width =  round(width/scale);
                height = round(height/scale);

                cout<<"Levels "<<levels<<endl;

                if(width < win_size.width || height < win_size.height)
            break;

            resize(img,img_new,Size(width,height));
            scale *= scale;
                }

                cout<<count<<endl;
                count++;
            }

            hogWorkEnd();
            fs.release();
          }
           else  running = false;
       }
}
```

For the first image it is correctly calculating HOG features for all levels but for the next image it takes the old value of width and height and in that case it break the following loop.

```
if(width < win_size.width || height < win_size.height)
break;
```

Can some one point my mistake. I tried to debug but unfortunately no success yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HOG feature calculation of each image takes old value of the following three parameters.
1. Width 
2. Height
3. Scale

And when it calculates HOG features for next image it break the loop immediately. A common programming mistake.